# Partitioned View ( union all in view ) in google big query or any database

Tags: database, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

Is there a disadvantage of using Partitioned view. Example what I mean as below.

https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/31/partitioned-views/

However instead of using date, I want to partition by other field type. e.g.
Product Type or Country.

so the view will be

```
Select '1' as Prod_type, 'USA' as Country , * 
from fact_Sales_1_USA
union all
Select '2' as Prod_type, 'UK' as Country , * 
from fact_Sales_2_UK
```

This way it will prevent query from reading the whole table and just limit to the particular Product Type and Region.

One of disadvantage is our course the update of data slightly more complex?

Will it slow down a query where I don't use the field above?

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery does not currently support [partitioning by non-date columns](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817). The only way to emulate this is to have a separate table for each product type or region, for example, and then use a [table wildcard to enable filtering on them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix).

If your tables have the following names, for example:

```
MyTable_USA_1
MyTable_USA_3
MyTable_UK_2
MyTable_France_1
...
```

You can create a logical view as:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  *,
    _TABLE_SUFFIX AS country_and_product
FROM `MyTable_*`;
```

Now when you query it, you can filter on the country (and optionally product number):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  * EXCEPT (country_and_product)
FROM CountryAndProductView
WHERE country_and_product LIKE 'UK_%'
  -- AND country_and_product LIKE '%_2'
```

One thing to keep in mind is that there is a limit of 1000 tables per query, so this approach won't work if you have too many combinations of countries and products. If that's the case, you may need to "partition" just by one of them rather than by both.

Comment: How would you combine the above with the date partition in big query?

Comment: You can't currently use _PARTITIONTIME from the table wildcard if the underlying tables are date-partitioned, but there is [an open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905833).